# How to load view swift more than one time?

Tags: ios, swift

I have one view (DataInputContainerView) and i load that view to DataController. This is my code for load DataInputContainerView to DataController

```
var heightInput: CGFloat = 50
lazy var inputContainerView: DataInputContainerView = {
    let dataInputContainerView = DataInputContainerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.heightInput))
    dataInputContainerView.dataController = self
    return dataInputContainerView
}()
```

That code was work. But i want to load again, for example

```
@IBAction func loadAgain(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.heightInput += 15
    // Put here to load that view again
}
```

I want make height view +15 and load again

Answer (score 0):

So you want code that will create multiple instances of your DataInputContainerView class?

Don't use a lazy property. That creates a single instance the first time it's called, and the returns the same instance each time thereafter.

Instead, create a function that returns a `DataInputContainerView`:

```
func makeDataInputContainerView(height: height: CGFloat) ->
  DataInputContainerView {
    let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, 
      height: height)
    let dataInputContainerView = DataInputContainerView(frame: rect)
    dataInputContainerView.dataController = self
    return dataInputContainerView
}
```

And then call it:

```
var height = 50

for (_ in 1...5) {
   var newDataInputContainerView = makeDataInputContainerView(height: height)
   self.view.addSubview(newDataInputContainerView)
}
```

Comment: But, can i call my data in DataInputContainerView? like, if i use my code before, i can call inputContainerView.textView

Comment: put them into an array if you don't know the numbers of the views or create more instance variable for them if you know

Comment: can you give an example to create variable for them?